# Create / Update an html table based on a subset of json dataset based on mouseover of a d3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I am trying to create a dynamic html table based on a user selection (mouse over a d3 graph). To this point I have been very lucky and I have been able to modify other's code snippets (largely from http://jsfiddle.net/U4CGz/7/) to get this far.

I have found other links that have the pieces but I have not been able to put it together into a working script (links not listed due to having low reputation)

My goals..

1. use an index value from mouse over of a d3 graphic
2. populate first column with a station ID (will not always be the same number of stations)
3. populate second column with corresponding discharge value using the same color from graph
4. populate third column based on a lookup... StationId : StationName
5. sort results based on a downstream predetermined order (not alphabetical)

partial data set below

```
    var dataset = [{
        'date': '201405221630',
            '10300200': 199,
            '10300000': 239
    }, {
        'date': '201405221645',
            '10300200': 199,
            '10300000': 239
    }, {
        'date': '201405221700',
            '10300200': 197,
            '10300000': 240
    }, ];
```

mousemove function seems to work while updateTable function doesn't work

```
    function mousemove() {
        var x0 = x_main.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
            i = bisectDate(dataset, x0, 1),
            d0 = dataset[i - 1].date,
            d1 = dataset[i].date,
            c = x0 - d0 > d1 - x0 ? [d1, i] : [d0, i - 1];
        //console.log(dataset[i]);
        circles.attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' + x_main(c[0]) + ',' + y_main(d.values[c[1]].value) + ')'
        });
        updateTable(c)
    }

    function updateTable(dateIndex) {
        //console.log(dateValue)
        d3.select("#th-date").text("Date: " + dateIndex[0]);
        //console.log(dataset[dateValue[1]])
        //console.log(dataset);
        var tbody = d3.select("discharge-table").append("tbody");
        var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("tr");

        var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function (row) {
            return dataset.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    name: d,
                    value: d[name]
                };
            });
        })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        });
    }
```

my code in its current state (works to a certain extent) is at http://jsfiddle.net/cjustin7/DCCe4/#base

As you can see in the code above or at my JSFiddle, I have not even started setting up the structure for my 4th and 5th goals. I am very new to html, css, javascript, and d3. I would be grateful to be directed or shown a working example or a suggestion of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your data set do not contain station ID and name

Comment: @Justin As jhyap mentioned, your dataset does not seem to have StationID and name fields. Could you clarify what the different fields in the dataset represent. Currently, it is only clear that each entry in the dataset has a 'date' entry. What do the other 2 fields (and their values) in each data point represent?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... Sometimes you get a little too close to what you are doing. Each record has a date field with an associated date value followed by n stations associated with n discharge values. In the dataset above there are 3 records and each record has a date and 2 stations / discharge  data pairs.

Comment: @JustinMayers I've edited the code based on your reply. Let me know in case it doesn't give the output you expected.

Comment: @jithinpt Thank you. Your code suggestions have taken care #2 and part of #3 goals listed above. In addition with your code snippet in hand I was able to figure out #4 and #5 goals. Could help me with the last part of my #3 goal? To restate it clearly.. I am looking to have the text in the second column only (discharge values) match the color of the corresponding line on the graph. I have tried to add `.style('color', function (d) {return colour(d.name);` to the cells variable but it predictably applies to the entire body and in this case it applies a seemingly random color. Thanks again.

Comment: @jithinpt Forgot to mention the updated code is at the same [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjustin7/DCCe4/#base).

Comment: @JustinMayers I've added an edit to the code below to color the cells as you mentioned.

Comment: @jithinpt Thanks for sticking with me and helping me all the way through this bit of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the data binding performed in `updateTable` seems to be incorrect. The way `rows` and `cells` is initialized is wrong.

**EDIT** I've changed the proposed code. The following code should give you the necessary table output

In the HTML, add the following `tbody` declaration to the markup for `discharge-table` (add it after `<thead>` has been declared)

```
<tbody id="discharge-table-body"></tbody>
```

Rewrite `updateTable` as follows:

```
function updateTable(dateIndex) {
   d3.select("#th-date").text("Date: " + dateIndex[0]);
   var tbody = d3.select("#discharge-table-body");

   var recordIndex = dateIndex[1]
   var record = dataset[recordIndex] // This is currently selected record in the graph
   var stationDischargeData = getStationDischargeData(record)
   tbody.selectAll(".data-row").remove()
   var rows = tbody.selectAll(".data-row")
    .data(stationDischargeData)
    .enter()
    .append("tr").attr("class", "data-row");

   var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
      .data(function(d) {return [d.station, d.discharge]})
      .enter()
      .append("td")
      .text(function(d) {return d})

}
```

And add a new function `getStationDischargeData` as shown below

```
function getStationDischargeData(record) {
   var stationDischargeData = []
   for (f in record) {
     if (f != "date") {
        stationDischargeData.push({station: f, discharge: record[f]})
     }
   }

  return stationDischargeData
}
```

These changes should enable you to populate the first two columns of the table with the data in `dataset`

**EDIT** In order to change the color the discharge value in the table to the color of the graph-line it corresponds to, change the portion that initializes `cells` in updateTable as follows:

```
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function (d) {
        return [d.station, {value: d.discharge, color: colour(d.station)}, d.stationName]
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .style('color', function (d) {
        if ((typeof d) == "object") {return d.color} else {return 'black'}
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        if ((typeof d) == "object") {return d.value} else {return d}
    })
```